# How do I know what a return value of zero means for NSDictionary's objectForKey method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

The documentation for NSDictionary says that the method `objectForKey` returns `nil` if the NSDictionary does not contain your key; however, isn't nil the same as zero?  If so, how do I know if the return value means that the dictionary contains the key mapped to zero or if that key is just non-existant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSDictionaries (and, indeed, all Cocoa collection objects) can only contain Objective-C objects, not C primitives like `int`. Therefore, were you to store `0` in a dictionary, you'd do it like this:

```
[myDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

and therefore, retrieving it would go like this:

```
NSNumber* resultObj = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
if (resultObj == nil)
{
    //Key didn't exist
}
else
{
    int result = [resultObj intValue];
    //Now do your work.
}
```

This concept of 'wrapping' a C primitive in an object to store it in a collection, then 'unwrapping' it on the other end is very common in Cocoa. (You might also look into `NSValue` if you're trying to work with non-number values.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:** Although the direction in memory `NULL` and `nil` point to happen to be `0x0` and it has always been and it may always be, you can't use that value for other purposes but to define an undefined address in memory. In the case of `NULL` it means an undefined pointer. `nil` means an undefined object pointer. The idea behind these `#define`s is that there's a rigid standard for programmers and programs to know and communicate undefined addresses in memory, and it could change to `0x42` in a new compiler or standard and NOTHING should happen. So, don't think `nil` or `NULL` as 0; yes they are, but that's a mere accident. It's not a feature. 
`nil` is not the same as 0. `nil` is an object pointer, 0 is a numeric value

Comment: Actually, technically, nil is defined as NULL, which in turn is defined as __DARWIN_NULL, which in turn is defined as (void*)0. So, yes, nil *is* the same as 0. But you're absolutely right that stylistically, they have very different usages.

Comment: if you set
 NSString * stringValue= 0 ;
it will not complain and when debug you find 
stringValue = nil